# I have a mib file how can I see the oid for a specific "object"?

Tags: snmp, mib, oid

I have seen some related questions here but they don't seem to answer my doubt.

I have several MIB files I'm reading them using a text editor (know any good free mib reader?)
I see the descriptions but don't know witch oid is using so I can place it on my snmpwalk query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Linux an OK browser is mbrowse..

http://sourceforge.net/projects/mbrowse/